# Exposing verificationToken in built-in user model - Loopback 3

Tags: rest, api, loopbackjs, loopback

Subject says it all really. Just trying to figure out how to expose the `verficationToken` property of the default built-in user model in Loopback 3.

I've tried adding it to the "scope" definition in users.json, it works for other fields but not for verificationToken. I've also made sure to remove it from the "hidden" array in users.json.

I've read the very limited information provided on white-listing [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Model-definition-JSON-file.html) (https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Model-definition-JSON-file.html) and it talks about overwriting the toJSON method of the model, but I'm not seeing much info on how to do that, particularly for a built-in model.

Anybody every dealt with this before? Thanks in advance for any tips you might provide!

Answer (score 0):

To access verification token,If you are using User.json by default it hides the password and verificationToken from accessing in rest api

By Default

```
"hidden": ["password", "verificationToken"],
```

change it to

```
"hidden": ["password"],
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response! Unfortunately, I've already done this to no effect...but I certainly didn't note that in the question and I should have. I'll update it.